# Aapt2 issue with jenkins build Android

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

I'm using Jenkins to build my android application. I have an issue with `Aapt2` when I'm trying to build task "assemble".
I have added the `android.enableAapt2 = true` but I still have the issue.

Error :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\9b13819df5a46cfa71ada9be5d91c322\res\layout\abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml: error: file not found.

  Command: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\bc9c8887a50f76d929803eb5bfe61459\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          D:\jenkins\workspace\DemoProject\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\9b13819df5a46cfa71ada9be5d91c322\res\layout\abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

Comment: What issue do you have? Is there any error shown?

Comment: I haved add the log error. The issue is with the task app:mergeDebugResources

Comment: I have resolve the issue by creating a  new env. var GRADLE_USER_HOME. It is used to update the path of gradle cache.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like aapt2 is having trouble parsing the file path (it's too long). You can either try upgrading to the newest android gradle plugin which has better support for long paths, or you can try moving your gradle cache closer to the C: root.